# Strategy for downloading high resolution images from server for retina display

Tags: iphone, ios, image, retina-display

So with the retina displays on iOS I usually have images with twice the size named @2x per apple's guidelines on how to do retina displays. But this naming convention only works with images in the app's bundle which I can't write to.

What is your strategy for pulling down high resolution images from a server?

Should I always just pull down the high res images (say 120x120 for a normal 60x60 image) and slap it into the uiimageview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to set retina Image you should

```
UIImage *image;  // from download
image=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Check first if you have a retina display

```
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    BOOL retina = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0 ? YES : NO;
```

if "retine == YES" , fetch the retina image you want

Comment: So.. if retina I fetch retina image, use your uiimage scale (I assume scale 2 means this image is 2x the size it should be). If not retina fetch the normal image (presumably from a different url), and use a normal uiimage?

Comment: yes, use "scale"  or you can just fetch retina image , but it use more memory